# Manually add sitemap located in s3 into google webmaster tools

Tags: amazon-s3, sitemap, google-search-console

I have an app running in Heroku. 
I am using sitemap_generator to generate sitemap and save it into s3.
I have added the robots.txt to contain my sitemap location.

My question are.

How can I know my sitemap are successfully find by search engine like google?

How can I monitor my sitemap?

If my sitemap is located in my app server I can add the sitemap manually into google webmaster tools for monitoring. Because when I click on "Test/Add sitemap" in Google webmaster tools, it default to the same server.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 13):

I got it to work.

Google has something called cross submission: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2007/10/dealing-with-sitemap-cross-submissions.html

You might want to visit this blog as well:
http://stanicblog.blogspot.sg/2012/02/how-to-add-your-sitemap-file-located-in.html

Thanks for your help, yacc.

Comment: I have tried this but the sitemap only shows up for the s3 site, not the main site... thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer your two first questions, one at a time (I'm not sure what you mean by '*how can I monitor my sitemap*' so I'll skip it):

## Manually submit a sitemap to Google

If you can't use Google webmaster form to submit your sitemap, use an HTTP get request to notify Google of your new site map.

If your sitemap is located at `https://s3.amazonaws.com/sitemapbucket/sitemap.gz` , first URL encode your sitemap URL (you can use this online [URL encoder/decoder](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) for that) then using *curl* or *wget* to submit your encoded URL to Google:

```
curl www.google.com/webmasters/tools/ping?sitemap=https%3A%2F%2Fs3.amazonaws.com%2Fsitemapbucket%2Fsitemap.gz
```

If your request is successful you'll get a 200 answer with a message like this:

```
... cut ...
<body><h2>Sitemap Notification Received</h2>
<br>
Your Sitemap has been successfully added to our list of Sitemaps to crawl. 
... cut ...
```

## Checking that Google knows about your new sitemap

Open **Webmaster Tools**, navigate to **Site sonfiguration->Sitemaps**, there you should see  the sitemaps that you've submited. It might take sometime for a new sitemap to show up there, so check frequently.

Comment: Thanks for your replied. I want to track my sitemap status located in s3 with Google Webmaster Tools. How can I do it? Because Google Webmaster Tools only allow me to add the sitemap located in the same server/domain, not s3.